# Get civi mailing with status = 'Complete' using API explorer

Tags: civimail, scheduled-job

What should be the way to get/find mailing with the status ='complete' using API explorer?

or is it the value which stores in civicrm_mailing.is_completed for each mailing?

or there is any other way to get such mailings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable via API Explorer.

- Entity is `Mailing`,
- The Action is `Get`, and
- The Parameter is `Mailing Completed = Yes`